# How to replace a character in a string with another string in C

Tags: c

Let's suppose i have this phrase:

> Hello $, Welcome!

I have to replace the '$' with a name, the result should be:

> Hello Name, Welcome!

For now i did this, but it copies only the name and the first part of the phrase:

```
char * InsertName(char * string, char * name)
{
    char temp;
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++)
    {
        if(string[i] == '$')
        {
            for(int k = i, j = 0; j < strlen(name); j++, k++)
            {
                temp = string[k+2];
                string[k]  = name[j];
                string[k+1] = temp;
            }
            return string;
        }

    }
    return "";
}
```

How can i shift all the elements after the name, so i can have the full string to be returned?

Comment: For one, how do you even know that `string` has enough bytes to hold the extended version? For two, you are overwriting parts of the old string in your inner "shift" loop.

Comment: i allocated like 1000 bytes of memory with malloc, i think it has enough space

Comment: @StefanoRaneri That will leak memory if you don't `free()` it later on...

Comment: i'm also using `free()` to deallocate the memory. I just need to modify the phrase.

Comment: Don't go by substitution route, it'll be painful later on. Rather, form different strings, concatenate them as needed and return the concatenated result.

Comment: If this is not one-time replacement, you might look into one of template engines, like [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/).

Comment: What should happen if `'$'` appears 2 times, 3 times, none at all?

Comment: Say `strlen(name)` is `N` and takes `N` time for `strlen(name)` to determine it. 
 `for(int k = i, j = 0; j < strlen(name); j++, k++)` is a wasteful re-computation of `strlen(name)`  being done N times when it is only needed once.  Suggest `for(int k = i, j = 0; name[j] != '\0';  j++, k++)` instead.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**Try this !!!**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char* replace(char* str, char* a, char* b)
{
    int len  = strlen(str);
    int lena = strlen(a), lenb = strlen(b);
    for (char* p = str; p = strstr(p, a); ++p) {
        if (lena != lenb) // shift end as needed
            memmove(p+lenb, p+lena,
                len - (p - str) + lenb);
        memcpy(p, b, lenb);
    }
    return str;
}
int main()
{
    char str[80] = "Hello $,Welcome!";
    printf("%s\n", replace(str, "$", "name"));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what is "this"?

Comment: gcc said: `warning: suggested parentheses around assignment used as truth value in the second argument` of the for loop.

Comment: The code  is correct, but is frequently a typo (assignment instead of comparision) and that's why gcc gives you a warning. If you really want to use assignment as a truth value, you may enclose it in parentheses to get rid of the warning.

Comment: `memmove(p + lenb, p + lena, len - (p - str) + lenb);` can readily move too much, memory not owned by `p` leading to _undefined behavior_ (UB).  Try `char str[26] = {0};
  for (int i=0; i<sizeof str; i++) str[i] = i + 'A';
  strcpy(str, "Hello $,Welcome!");
  printf("<%s>\n", replace(str, "$", "name"));
  for (int i=0; i<sizeof str; i++) printf(" %c", str[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`sprintf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) to *print* the output on a *C-string*, emulating the work done by `printf()`:

> **Edit:** You will have to include these two headers for this function to work:

> ```
> #include <stdlib.h>
> #include <memory.h>
> ```

An implementation of what you are trying to implement:

```
char* InsertAt(unsigned start, const char* source, const char* target, const char* with,
               unsigned * position_ret)
{
    const char * pointer = strstr(source, target);
    if (pointer == NULL)
    {
        if (position_ret != NULL)
            *position_ret = UINT_MAX;
        return _strdup(source);
    }
    if (position_ret != NULL)
        *position_ret = (unsigned)(pointer - source);
    char* result = calloc(strlen(source) + strlen(with) + strlen(pointer), sizeof(char));
    sprintf_s(result, strlen(source) + strlen(with) + strlen(pointer), "%.*s%.*s%.*s",
        (signed)(pointer - source), _strdup(source),
        (signed)strlen(with) + 1, _strdup(with),
        (signed)(strlen(pointer) - strlen(target)), _strdup(pointer + strlen(target)));
    return result;
}
```

> ***Example:***

> ```
> #define InsertAtCharacter(src, ch, with) InsertAt(0u, (src), \
> ```

```
                          (char[]){ (char)(ch), '\0' }, (with), NULL)
```

> ```
> int main(void)
> {
>     printf("%s", InsertAtCharacter("Hello $, Welcome!", '$', "Name"));
>     return 0;
> }
> ```